# Laravelからmysqlへのマイグレーションの際に起こるエラー

Tags: mysql, laravel

Laravelで`php artisan migrate`を実行した際に不明な認証と書かれたエラーが発生をしたので、下記にあるサイトの通りに変更を加えたところ、再度エラーが発生し、エラーの内容は不明なデータベースと書かれていました。

そこで調べたところ、データベースが作成されていない事が原因の可能性があるという事だったので、
DBuserからmyqppデータベースを作成して、再度`php artisan migrate`を実行したのですが、依然として同じようなエラーが発生してしまいます。

原因は何でしょうか？

.env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myapp
DB_USERNAME=DBuser
DB_PASSWORD=DBuser-24
```

エラー

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'myapp' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = myapp and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| myqpp              |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

mysql関連
DBuser：ログインできています。
myqpp：作成しました。

mysqlバージョン：mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

[SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = hogehoge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')](https://qiita.com/econbusi/items/a3d0fd12c3450a833e86)

Comment: エラーメッセージのとおり myapp という名前のデータベースは存在していません（myqpp は typo？）

Comment: ありがとうございます。aとqを撃ち間違えていました。そしてマイグレーションが成功しました。

Answer (score 0):

aとqの打ち間違いだと分かりました。
誠に申し訳ありませんでした。